# React, import external json rather than local

Tags: reactjs, axios

I do have a class which is working nice when i do have a local json file.
But it is not working when the json is on external source.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Components from "../components/components.js";
import datas from "../components/data.json";
import axios from 'axios';

const data2 = datas.results[0];

export default class HomePage extends React.Component {

    state = {
        json: []
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(`http://external_json_url`)
            .then(res => {
                const json = res.data;
                this.setState({ json });
                const data = this.state.json.results[0];
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data2); // get the same result in the console
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {data2.Composant.map(block => Components(block))}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

if i replace `{data2.Composant.map(block => Components(block))}` by `{data.Composant.map(block => Components(block))}` I get some  Error : Line 28:18:  'data' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: What *are* you getting back? We can't see your data.

Comment: Data is declared inside the `then` block, so it's unaccessible from `render`. Why don't you use the state ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel : how will i do that please ?

Comment: @DaveNewton : When using data2 i get all the way i want ... when getting data i get only an error : Line 28:18: 'data' is not defined no-undef.

Comment: You declare `data2` before *anything* has happened. You try to access state before `setState` has finished (`setState` is async). You try to use `data2` in your render when the values you're trying to map are (presumably) in state. It might be worth the time to take a step back and run through a React tutorial or two.

Answer (score 0):

Try using states.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Components from "../components/components.js";
import datas from "../components/data.json";
import axios from 'axios';

const data2 = datas.results[0];

export default class HomePage extends React.Component {

state = {
    json: [],
    data:{}
}

componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`http://external_json_url`)
        .then(res => {
            const json = res.data;
            this.setState({ json });
            const data = this.state.json.results[0];
            this.setState({data});
            console.log(data2); // get the same result in the console
        })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data.Composant.map(block => Components(block))}
        </div>

    )
}
}
```